# Identify duplicate records in single column with large volume in same column using python

Tags: python, database, duplicates

We have large volume of data in a single column and we need to identify duplicates/possible duplicates using python.

Las Vegas Strip, Blvd S

3745 Las Vegas Blvd S

3745 Las Vegas Boulevard South, Las Vegas Strip

---

Raintree At Polo Towers Las Vegas - Las Vegas

Polo Towers By Raintree

---

Polo Towers By Diamond Resorts

Diamond Resorts at Polo Towers - Las Vegas

I need to identify instance like the above in my database. Could any one help on this with python, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could split the string by ',' and search the table by each element outputted after splinting it up, something like this:

```
SELECT @variable = top(1), columnname from yourtable

SELECT * from youtable WHERE Split(@variable) LIKE '%"+columname+"%'
```

1. You need a Split function by comma or any other delimiter
2. You have to iterate for each element from yourtable, in my example I used only the first (TOP(1))

Comment: Thanks for you reply, But im looking for more efficiently because i have large number of data volume.